# Finding Magnetic Declination

Tags: spherical-harmonics

I am trying to find an exact "plug and chug" formula for calculating magnetic declination given time, date, latitude, longitude, elevation, etc.  Everywhere I look tells me to use their web based calculator.  I was hoping there was a way that I could figure this out myself and maybe code my own calculator.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think an "exact plug and chug" formula exists for this problem.

A free fully documented implementation that does the job is available here:

https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/WMM/soft.shtml

It's a substantial piece of software.

You might be able to read the code and the documentation and put together a crude approximation of your own.